# Converting coordinates to lat lon in Madrid?

Tags: coordinate-system, spain

I am using Python script for accessing [this](http://informo.munimadrid.es/informo/tmadrid/pm.xml) API for getting madrid traffic data. But I am really confused on how to get the geographic coordinates from this data. It has 2 fields st_x and st_y which I feel contain the information for the coordinates. I want to get those coordinates in lat long.

[image: Data for one location]

Comment: Welcome! What software do you have access to? The coordinate reference system is probably [EPSG:25830](http://www.epsg-registry.org) or less likely, EPSG:23030.

Comment: Ohh, but there are 2 coordinates for st_x and st_y so total 4 coordinates in total how does that makes sense.

Comment: The commas are the decimal delimiter.

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much @mkennedy !!!

Comment: Please always provide data as formatted text rather than pictures so that can be easily copied for testing. Also, any coding question should include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: EPSG:25830 worked thanks a lot again I am really grateful! I was looking for this since one week.

Comment: @PolyGeo sure I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful to calculate the coordinates: https://github.com/bewest/proj4js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/utm-latlng

Comment: I used pyproj for conversion